# Not getting email field from Facebook Api

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am working on facebook login in node js so I need some of user's details but I am not able to get an email even I have mentioned it in scope.
so I have tried it in postman with the token generated by facebook SDK and graph API so I am getting an email from token generated by Facebook Graph API but not with Facebook SDK's token please help me with this... I don't know what is the issue...

here is my code

```
FB.login(result => {
    if (result.authResponse) {
      return this.http.post(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/facebook`, {access_token: result.authResponse.accessToken})
          .toPromise()
          .then(response => {
            var token = response.headers.get('x-auth-token');
            if (token) {
              localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
            }
            resolve(response.json());
          })`
          .catch(() => reject());
    } else {
      reject();
    }
  }, {scope: 'public_profile,email,gender'})
```

here is response:

[image]

Comment: Did it ask you for the email permission on the login dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a new app on the Facebook developer and it worked...Thanks